# When I tried to run ng new in one of my folders on Mac I am getting error an error stating package install failed and schematic workflow failed

Tags: package, installation, semantics

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmN8D.png)

how to fix the error which I am getting as shown in screenshot above ? I had used home-brew to install npm and node

Comment: It good to add commands causing the failure and single line of the error in the question which help file doing a textual search. BTW whats does your ...debug.log file says ?

Comment: the debug.log file  is showing permission denied. I used ng new comp command but on running it showed the errors in screen shot. I am using Angular 9 on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your user dont have required access to complete the package installation so try

```
sudo ng new comps
```